Vercel Deployment Failing with 'Permission Denied' on npm run build (Exits with 126) in React + Vite Project
I’m trying to deploy my React application, built with Vite as a bundler, to Vercel, but the deployment fails with the following error.
sh: line 1: /vercel/path0/node_modules/.bin/vite: Permission denied
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 126

This error occurs during the build process when Vercel is running the npm run build command. The specific issue appears to be a permission problem when trying to execute the vite binary located inside the node_modules/.bin/ folder.
Steps I’ve Taken:

Local Build Check:
I’ve tried running the build command locally using:

npm run build

This works perfectly fine, and the dist folder is generated as expected without any issues.

I tried running npm install and npm run build locally, which works without errors.

I’ve tried clearing the cache on Vercel and redeploying the project, but the error persists.

I also tried overriding the build command directly in the Vercel environment settings, as well as modifying environment variables, but this did not resolve the issue.

I ensured that my package.json specifies the correct Node version under the "engines" key ("node": "18.x").


Is there something I’m missing in the Vercel deployment configuration, or do I need to address the file permissions before deploying? I’ve tried setting up environment variables and overriding the build command, but that hasn’t worked either.
